# My php_curl module desactive itself and sometimes reactive in IIS

Tags: php, iis

I have IIS 10, PHP 5.4.45. My php.ini contains the line

```
extension=php_curl.dll
```

I have php_curl.dll in my extension repository.

Sometimes, when I restart IIS, I have curl in `phpinfo()` and then it disappears from it without explication.

Could someone help me?

Comment: have you removed semicolon beginning of this line extension=php_curl.dll?

Comment: Yes, I did, as I said, sometimes it works